# Nullish Coalescing in ScriptLab

Tags: typescript, office-js, office-addins, coalesce, scriptlab

My function parameter should accept a 0 or false value for an optional parameter, so I am using the ?? operator instead of the || operator for default value assignment to avoid a valid value overwritten with the default value.

So, here is the sample function code:

```
function myfunction(param1: number, param2?: number): number 
{
  param2 = param2 ?? 1

  console.log(param2)

  return param2
}
```

However, even though the function works without problems, the ScriptLab editor reports a syntax error.

[image: ScriptLab syntax error warning]

Is this a known ScriptLab bug?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error? The red underline doesn't tell us, so we can only guess. It could be that the global `console` object does not exist in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jimmy. I just updated the image to show more info - it is not about the console object, it just shows error becasue of the first error on the ?? operator. As I said, the function works without problems, so it is a false-positive, and I believe it is a ScriptLab bug, but maybe it is something known.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug, but the `ScriptLab` add-in is available with a source code (open source project). You can find the add-in's source code available publicly on GitHub - https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab. So, you may try debugging it to find the cause. Even if it is maintained by the Office team, nobody can stop you from adding or fixing things.